# When was the phrase "it is a good day to die" first said in a Star Trek [franchise] production?

Tags: star-trek

Watching DS9 and heard the phrase '***it is a good day to die***' and couldn't remember hearing it in early TNG episodes, but thinking it surely it came from TNG first, I just can't recall which episode and who said it.

Canon and book answers are viable, but looking for real world timing, not in-universe (ie - if it was first written in a book and then incorporated into the series later, that is fine (and interesting) but a book written in 2015 about the history of Khaless uttering the phrase centuries in the past wouldn't count)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [first use](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bline%7Cgood%20day%20to%20die,%7D)) in Trek appears to be [TNG: Sins of the Father](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/165.htm) in Season 3, aired in March 1990.

> **DURAS:** *You will not wear the emblems of our people. You are a fool and your challenge can only result in a fool's death.*
>
> **WORF:** ***It is a good day to die***, Duras, and the day is not yet over.